# How do I detect if a template parameter is a builtin or not?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to use SFINAE to stop from explicitly calling the destructor because MSVS 2010 considers it an error when done on a builtin type pointer.

How would I do this?

Comment: No, that relies on the fact that the class has a typedef of a particular name.  The class may not have that or any typedef, yet I still wan to determine if it is a class or not.

Comment: which intrinsic type is not included in std::is_arithmetic?

Comment: [This code](http://ideone.com/w8uaGv) compiles successfully with my copy of MSVC2010. Whatever problem you might have lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to specialize a function so it is called for fundamental data types in C++.

```
template < class T>
void delete_object(T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type* = 0) {
    // Do nothing because this is not an object
}

template<class T>
void delete_object(T* object) {
    delete object;
}

int main()
{
    int arithmetic1 = 1;
    delete_object(arithmetic1);
    float arithmetic2 = 1;
    delete_object(arithmetic2);
    Object* object1 = new Object();
    delete_object(object1);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the other fundamental tests

```
std::is_integral<>       - 'char' up to 'long long'
std::is_floating_point   - 'float' up to 'long double'
std::is_signed<>         - signed types
std::is_unsigned<>       - unsigned types
std::is_arithmetic       - is_integral<> OR is_floating_point<>
std::is_fundamental<>    - is_arithmetic<> OR 'void'
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot about some of these, didn't know about others.

Comment: I would have to agree with the answer below, std::is_class<> could be a better choice.  But I also know that often the simplified example hides what you actually are trying to do, so I have tried to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at it from the wrong angle: You shouldn't exclude what does *not* work, you should detect what does work. In your case, you are trying to check if a given type `T` is a class and hence you could call the destructor.

That said, you want [`std::is_class`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class). If it is not available for your compiler, there is [Boost.TypeTraits' `boost::is_class`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_class.html) available which works with VC++ 8 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

```
With the following type function we can determine whether a type is a class type:

// traits/isclasst.hpp 

template<typename T> 
class IsClassT { 
  private: 
    typedef char One; 
    typedef struct { char a[2]; } Two; 
    template<typename C> static One test(int C::*); 
    template<typename C> static Two test(…); 
  public: 
    enum { Yes = sizeof(IsClassT<T>::test<T>(0)) == 1 }; 
    enum { No = !Yes }; 
}; 

This template uses SFINAME principle.
The following program uses this type function to test whether certain types and objects are class types:

// traits/isclasst.cpp 

#include <iostream> 
#include "isclasst.hpp" 

class MyClass { 
}; 

struct MyStruct { 
}; 

union MyUnion { 
}; 

void myfunc() 
{ 
} 

enumE{e1}e; 

// check by passing type as template argument 
template <typename T> 
void check() 
{ 
    if (IsClassT<T>::Yes) { 
        std::cout << " IsClassT " << std::endl; 
    } 
    else { 
        std::cout << " !IsClassT " << std::endl; 
    } 
} 

// check by passing type as function call argument 
template <typename T> 
void checkT (T) 
{ 
    check<T>(); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    std::cout << "int: "; 
    check<int>(); 

    std::cout << "MyClass: "; 
    check<MyClass>(); 

    std::cout << "MyStruct:"; 
    MyStruct s; 
    checkT(s); 

    std::cout << "MyUnion: "; 
    check<MyUnion>(); 

    std::cout << "enum:    "; 
    checkT(e); 

    std::cout << "myfunc():"; 
    checkT(myfunc); 
} 
The program has the following output:

int:      !IsClassT 
MyClass:  IsClassT 
MyStruct: IsClassT 
MyUnion:  IsClassT 
enum:     !IsClassT 
myfunc(): !IsClassT
```